# SQL+Openxml+how to store NVARCHAR data

Tags: sql, openxml

hello i am using the following stored procedure to insert the xml data in a table.

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExpertSystem_SET_QuestionData]
@XmlQue     NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
set nocount on
 DECLARE @XmlHdl INT 

BEGIN


SET @XmlQue=N''+@XmlQue

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XmlHdl OUTPUT,@XmlQue

    INSERT INTO ExpertSystem_Master 
    SELECT QIdx,@TemplateId,QDetailsx,IsYesx,IsNox,Eligibleyesx,Eligiblenox,0,0
    FROM 
    OPENXML(@XmlHdl,'/Template/QueInfo',1)
    WITH
    (    QIdx           INT '@QId',
         QDetailsx      Ntext '@QDetails',
         IsYesx         Ntext  '@IsYes', 
         IsNox          Ntext  '@IsNo', 
         Eligibleyesx   CHAR(1) '@Eligibleyes',
         Eligiblenox    CHAR(1) '@Eligibleno'
    )
   END
```

In this case i am passing the values to parameter as

```
ExpertSystem_SET_QuestionData '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><Template TId="1"><QueInfo QId="1" QDetails="Are you " IsYes="Yes" IsNo="No" Eligibleyes="Y" Eligibleno="N"/><QueInfo QId="2" QDetails="  राज्य  " IsYes="Yes" IsNo="No" Eligibleyes="Y" Eligibleno="N"/><QueAns QId="1" isMsgFlag="N" Msg="you are not Eligible"/><QueAns QId="2" isMsgFlag="N" Msg="you are not eligible"/></Template>'
```

The data is inserted , but it is inserted as **?????** instead of ** "राज्य  "**.

When i am calling the procedure as

```
ExpertSystem_SET_QuestionData 'N<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><Template TId="1"><QueInfo QId="1" QDetails="Are you Domicile of maharashtra" IsYes="Yes" IsNo="No" Eligibleyes="Y" Eligibleno="N"/><QueInfo QId="2" QDetails="Have you passed Secondary  School 10th Examination?महाराष्ट्र राज्य मार्ग परिवहन महामंडळ " IsYes="Yes" IsNo="No" Eligibleyes="Y" Eligibleno="N"/><QueAns QId="1" isMsgFlag="N" Msg="you are not Eligible"/><QueAns QId="2" isMsgFlag="N" Msg="you are not eligible"/></Template>'
```

i get the error as "The XML parse error 0xc00ce556 occurred on line number 1, near the XML text "N "

can you please help me out with the issue,as the procedure is called at run time so any data can be passed to the @XmlQue variable.
so how am i supposed to append "N" with the @XmlQue variable ???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `N` should come before the xml value.

```
ExpertSystem_SET_QuestionData N'<?xml version="1.0" ...
```